# react native - payment with PayPal v2/orders

Tags: android, ios, react-native, paypal

I am implementing PayPal in React Native, following the documentation for  [PayPal Payments v2 API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/)

Here is the step by step of my checkout:

1. Use https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token to get token.
2. Use https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders to create an order
3. Use approve link for clients to accept payment
4. I set the `return_url` to be `https://www.google.com/`. After clients accept the payment, I receive the `return_url` `https://www.google.com/?token=<order_id>&PayerID=<payer_id>`

At this point I'm stuck: how can I use the information `order_id` and `payer_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next step is to do a [v2/orders capture](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_capture) of that `order_id`

Assuming success, the response's payments -> capture -> id value is what you should persist in your database for accounting purposes, as this is what will be searchable as the Transaction ID in the paypal.com account.

(The `order_id` has no accounting value, and should only be kept around ~1 month for debug purposes.)